# Problem of Separable Metric Space, Isolated points and countable sets

Tags: metric-spaces

How to prove that if a metric space $(E, d)$ is separable and $A\subseteq E$ is a set where all points are isolated then A is countable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every separable metric space is second countable, meaning that it has a countable base $\mathscr{B}$ for the topology. Suppose that $A$ is a subset of $E$ in which every point is isolated. Then for each $x\in A$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $B_x\cap A=\{x\}$. The map $A\to\mathscr{B}:x\mapsto B_x$ is injective ($1$-$1$), so ... ?

Comment: @leo: That's the point of my answer, except that I was trying to leave a little work for the OP.

Comment: This provides the way (I've seen so far) one prove that a space is not separable, namely, by finding a totally disconnected uncountable subset.

Comment: Brian M. Scott. The definition of isolated point that I got in my course of analysis says that $x$ is an isolated point of A if $\exists$ $r>0$ tal que $$B(x, r)\cap A=\{x\}$$ with $B(x, r)=\{y\in E: d(x, y)<r\}$. The set $B_x$ is an open set containing $x$.                                                                                                        As obtained that $B_x\cap A=\{x\}$?

Comment: @Roiner: The set $B(x,r)$ of that definition might not belong to $\mathscr{B}$, but since $\mathscr{B}$ is a base, there is some $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq B(x,r)$. To get the countable base $\mathscr{B}$, let $D$ be a countable dense set in $E$, and let $$\mathscr{B}=\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):x\in D\text{ and }n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;.$$

Comment: @Brian. I think there is a problem with your function.  How do you know that dont exists distinct sets $B'_a$ and $B''_a$ in $\mathscr{B}$ such that $a\in B_a''$ and $a\in B''_a$. Because if this happens then $a\rightarrow B'_a$ and $a\rightarrow B''_a$  and then your function would not function

Comment: @Roiner: Of course there is more than one member of $\mathscr{B}$ that **could** be chosen, but the function that I define chooses **one** of them. It doesn’t matter which one is chosen: every function formed in that way is injective and therefore shows that $A$ is countable.

Comment: You're right Brian. Thanks!!

Comment: @Roiner: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Brian. may exist a subset A of real numbers with uncountable number of isolated points?

Comment: @Roiner: No, that’s impossible. If $x$ is an isolated point of $A$, there is an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $|x-a|\ge\epsilon_x$ for each $a\in A$. Let $I$ be the set of isolated points of $A$, and for each $x\in I$ let $U_x=\left(x-\frac12\epsilon_x,x+\frac12\epsilon_x\right)$; then $\{U_x:x\in I\}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of open intervals in $\Bbb R$. Such a family must be countable, since each $U_x$ must contain a different rational number, and there are only countably many rationals. Thus, $I$ must also be countable.

Comment: @Roiner: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 9):

**Definition.**  *Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space.*

- *A base of open sets for $E$ is a family $\mathscr{B}$ of open subsets of $E$ such that, for any open subset
  $O$ of $E$, there is collection $\{O_i\}_{i\in I}$ contained in
  $\mathscr{B}$ such that* $$O=\bigcup_{i\in I} O_i.$$
- *If $F\subseteq E$, when we say that $F$ is a subspace of $E$, we are considering the metric space $(F,\rho)$, where*
  $$\rho=d\big|_{F\times F}.$$

It is a good exercise to prove (one direction is provided in a Brian's comment) that:

**Theorem 1.** *Let $E$ be a metric space. $E$ is separable if and only if $E$ has a countable base of open sets.*

From this follows:

**Corollary 2.** *Let $E$ be a metric space. $E$ is separable if and only if all its subspaces are separable.*

*Proof.* Assume first that $E$ is separable. By Theorem 1, there exist a countable base of open sets $\mathscr{B}$. Let $F$ a subspace of $E$. Then the family $\mathscr{B}'=\{O\cap F : O\in \mathscr{B}\}$ is countable base of open sets for $F$. By Theorem 1 we conclude $F$ is separable.

Conversely, suppose that $E$ is such that all its subspaces are separable. $E$ is a subspace of $E$, so $E$ is separable.

From Theorem 1 we also get:

**Lema 3.** *Let $E$ be a separable metric space. If $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of pairwise disjoint, open, nonempty sets, then $I$ is countable.*

*Proof.* Since $E$ is separable we can assume that there is a base of open sets $\mathscr{B}=\{O_j\}_{j\in\Delta}$ with $\Delta\subset \Bbb N$.

Since the open sets in $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ are pairwise disjoint and nonempty, for each $i\in I$, you can pick (axiom of choice possibly needed here) an element $x_i\in U_i$. Notice that the $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ are necessarily pairwise distinct.

Because $\mathscr{B}$ is a base of open sets, for each $i\in I$ there exist a $j_i\in\Delta$ such that
$$x_i\in O_{j_i}\subseteq U_i.$$

Notice that $i\neq k$ implies $j_i\neq j_k$. Otherwise there would be a pair of open sets in $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ whose intersection is not empty.

Then, the function $f:I\to\Delta$ given by
$$f(i)=j_i$$
is an injection from $I$ to $\Delta$, a countable set. Therefore $I$ must be countable.

Now, the answer to your question:

**Theorem 4.** *Let $E$ be a metric space. If $E$ is separable and $A$ is a subset of $E$ such that all its points are isolated, then $A$ is countable.*

*Proof.* Consider $A$ as subspace of $E$. By Corollary 2, $A$ is separable.

Since all the points of $A$ are isolated, for each $x\in A$ there exist a $r_x\gt 0$ such that
$$B(x,r_x)\cap A=\{x\}.$$
Thus 
$$\{B(x,r_x)\cap A\}_{x\in A}$$ is a family of pairwise disjoint open subsets of $A$. Since $A$ is separable, by Lemma 3, this family must be countable. Since there is exactly one set in that family for each element of $A$,$A$ must be countable.

Finally, it is worth to point out that

**Corollary 5.** *Let $E$ be a metric space. If there exist a uncountable subset $A$ of $E$ such that all its points are isolated then $E$ is not separable*

Answer (score 1):

Assume $A$ is uncountable. Since a point $a\in A$ is isolated form other points in $A$, there is an open ball $U_a$ of radius $r/2$ about $a$ where $0<r< \text{min}_{b\in A, b\neq a}d(a,b)$. Check that $U_a\cap U_b = \phi$. Then the open subspcae $\cup_{a\in A}U_a$ of $A$ is not seperable, it has no countably dense subset. This makes a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, every CCC (Countable Chain Condition space) has countable isolated points. Note that every separable space is CCC. Refer [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356334/separable-space-and-countable/356802#356802).

> Proof: Suppose not. Let $E=\{x_\xi: \xi\in \omega_1\}$, where $x_\xi$ is an isolated for each $\xi \in \omega_1$. Then it has uncountable disjoint open sets $\{\{x_\xi\}: \xi\in \omega_1\}$, which leads a contradiction.

Comment: What is $\omega_1$?

Answer (score 0):

$(E,d)$ separable means there exist a countable dense subset $D=\{x_n:n\geq 1\}\subset E$.

Now $x \in A$ isolated means that there exist an  $\epsilon$-ball centered at $x$ containing no points other than $x$. If $x \notin D$, then this ball contains no points of $D$ whatsoever, but this contradicts the density of $D$. Hence $x \in D$.

We have shown that $A\subset D$. Since $D$ is countable, it follows that $A$ is countable also.