# complete proof of non-separability of D space

Tags: general-topology, skorohod-space

Let $D$ be a set of *càdlàg* functions on $[0,1]$.

Define $f_\alpha(\cdot) \equiv 1(\cdot \ge \alpha)$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$, which is obviously in $D$.

Then, if we denote $|| \cdot ||$ as a uniform metric, then $||f_\alpha - f_\beta||=1$ for any $\alpha \neq \beta$.

I learned this implies non-separability of $D$ space, but I failed to complete the proof.

Who can give me any hint or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $(D,\|.\|)$ were separable, any subset would be separable, in particular $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in [0,1]}$. But it's discrete and non-numerable, so it's not separable.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that a subset of separable set is also separable. Thanks!

Comment: One who is curious of that, refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516886/prove-that-a-subset-of-a-separable-set-is-itself-separable