# Is a metrizable subspace of a separable space separable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a (Tychonoff) separable topological space (whose weight does not exceed $2^\omega$) and $M$ be a metrizable subspace of $X$. Is true that $M$ is separable?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516886/prove-that-a-subset-of-a-separable-set-is-itself-separable

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $X=[0;1]^{\frak c}$ be a Tychonoff cube. Then $X$ is separable, $w(X)=\frak c$, but it contains a discrete space $M=\{e_\alpha:\alpha<\frak c\}$ (where each $e_\alpha=(e_\alpha)_{\beta, \beta<\frak c}$,  $(e_\alpha)_{\alpha}=1$, and $(e_\alpha)_{\beta}=0$  provided $\beta\ne\alpha$) of size $\frak c$.

Comment: Indeed, any completely regular space of weight $\le 2^\omega$ embeds as a subspace into $X$ (universal space theorem), among which there are many non-separable ones.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S$ be the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology), and let $X=S\times S$, the Sorgenfrey plane. $S$ is separable, since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $S$, so $X$ is separable. $X$ is first countable and of cardinality $2^\omega$, so its weight is clearly no more than $2^\omega$ (and in fact it is $2^\omega$. However, the set $D=\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in S\}$ is a closed, discrete subset of cardinality $2^\omega$. Being discrete, it is metrizable, and it’s clearly not separable.