# Is $(l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, d))$ a Polish space? (Compacts with non empty interior)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of all bounded sequence of real numbers. Consider in $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ the restriction of the product metric, i.e,
$$
d(X,Y)=\dfrac{1}{2^i}\dfrac{|x_i-y_i|}{1+|x_i-y_i|}
$$

**Claim 1:**  $(l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, d))$ is complete.

In fact, let $ (X_n)$  be a Cauchy sequence in  $(l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, d)).$
So given $\epsilon>$ there is $N$ s.t $m,n>N$   implies $d(X_n,X_m)<\epsilon.$
In particular for each  fixed $i$  we can choose $N$ in such way  that $m,n>N$ implies   $|x_n^i-x_m^i|<\epsilon.$ Therefore for each fixed $i$ the 
sequence $(x^i_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, so this sequece  must have a limit $x^i$. Set $X=(x¹,x²,\ldots, x^i,\ldots)$. We claim that 
$X\in l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, in fact observe that 
$$
|x^i|\leq|x^i-x_n^i|+|x_n^i|
$$
and 
$$
|x^i-x_n^i|\leq|x_m^i-x^i|+|x_n^i-x_m^i|.
$$
So we can choose $N$ s.t $m,n>N$ imples $|x_m^i-x^i|<\epsilon$,
$|x_n^i-x_m^i|<\epsilon$  which implies 
$$
|x_i|\leq 2\epsilon+ K_n
$$
for all $i$ where $K_n=\sup_i|x_i|$, finishing the proof

**Claim 2:** $(l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, d))$ is separable. This is 
proved in this post: 
[Prove that a subset of a separable set is itself separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516886/prove-that-a-subset-of-a-separable-set-is-itself-separable)

**Claim 3**: Consider the sets $\Omega_k=[-k,k]^{ \mathbb{N}}$, this sets are compacts in $(l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, d)).$ In fact an open cover of $\Omega_k$  has   the form $\{O_{\lambda}\cap l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\}$ where 
$O_\lambda $  is an open set in the product space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, now note that $\{O_{\lambda}\}$ is an open cover of $\Omega_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which is  compact, so we can extract an finite open subcover
$\{O_1, \ldots,O_k\}$ of $\Omega_k$, finally observe that
$\{O_{i}\cap l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\}_{i=1}^k$ is 
a subcover to $\Omega_k$ in $(l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, d))$
therefore $\Omega_k$ is compact in the subspace topology.

**My Goals:**
My desires with this reasoning is to show that some of 
this compacts  are non empty interior. Once $(l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, d))$
is a Polish space and $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})=\bigcup \Omega_k$ we can use the Baire Theorem in order to get at last one $\Omega_k$ non empty interior.

**Is this reasoning correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that in the product topology the bounded sequences are dense and not closed. So they're not complete in the product topology metric. So the argument breaks down.

Comment: Is there some way to prove that some of this $\Omega_k$ has non empty interior?

Comment: @Eduardo All $\Omega_k$ have empty interior in the product topology.