# Proving that the closed unit sphere of a separable normed space is separable

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $L$ be a separable normed linear space. Show that its closed unit sphere $S=\{x\in L : \|x\|=1\}$ is also separable.

I am having quite a hard time with this, given a complete space $L$ then I would be able to prove it but how should I go about this now

Edit: Yes I am aware a separable metric space is second countable

Please help!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516886/prove-that-a-subset-of-a-separable-set-is-itself-separable