# Every set of non-overlapping disks in the plane is at most countable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R^2}$, the set of points inside a circle is a disk. Can we claim that every set of non-overlapping disks in the plane is at most countable?

My intuition says it must be countable by choosing some rational points from the disk but I am not sure about my claim.

Thanks for your help .

Comment: For a generalization to separable spaces, and for a counterexample which shows that a space need not be separable if it has this property, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356334/separable-space-and-countable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's absolutely the way to go! Enumerate the rational points in some sequence, and for each disk $D$ let $n_D$, be the least positive integer $n$ such that the $n$th rational point in the sequence lies in $D$. The map $D\mapsto n_D$ gives an injection into the positive integers from the set of disks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

We need an injective function from a given set of disks into
the countable set $Q \times Q$. The idea is to pick in each disk a point both of
whose coordinates are rational numbers. Since the disks are disjoint, no pair
of rational numbers is repeated for different disks, so the association disk to
(element of $Q \times Q$) is one-to-one.